# Pandoc HTML to docx font

Tags: html, ms-word, pandoc

I have followed every Google search on the topic, but nothing seems to pan out.  Is there a standard way to tell pandoc what the standard fontface should be?  I've tried the "template" and the "reference-docx" options to no avail.

This has to be a common request.  But I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: If you have MS-word, It have inbuild HTML conversion option which works fine for me.
`ActiveDocument.Range.InsertFile (file)`. Downloading Pandoc as looks good. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Pandoc monospace font size or style in DOCX output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346388/changing-the-pandoc-monospace-font-size-or-style-in-docx-output)