# Modify font name and size when exportng to docx with Pandoc

Tags: haskell, docx, pandoc

I'm writing a `Haskell` program to export data to `docx` fileformat with `pandoc` and by default, the font size is 12pt and I would like to set it to 10pt.

Is it possible with `pandoc` to set the font size and the font name when exporting a pandoc document to `docx` (and by extension to `odt`) ?

Is it possible to modify these values just for a paragraph a not only for the whole document?

---

*Note : My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346388/changing-the-pandoc-monospace-font-size-or-style-in-docx-output) because I want to make a `docx` document from a Haskell program and not from command line.*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28346388/246886

Comment: there's nothing fundamentally different you can do with pandoc as a library than pandoc the commandline utility, it's always about the pandoc AST/internal document model which doesn't hold layout information.

Comment: @mb21 note that JeanJoux is writing data that are somehow generated from a haskell program.

Comment: This will have to be handled by the reference docx, which contains all references to e.g. font sizes and other non-semantic material; pandoc's representation doesn't know anything about this. If the section in question is to get a different font size it will have to be semantically different in a way the reference docx can understand.